# how to form JSON Object

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, json

I have a Table for categories , which stores `Hierarchical Data` in the following format

`NodeID`--->`ParentID`--->`NodeName`

I want to select categories in the following manner for which i need to return a `JSON Object` in a predefined format.

**JSON FORMAT**

```
"Option 1": {"Suboption":200},
"Option 2": {"Suboption 2": {"Subsub 1":201, "Subsub 2":202},
             "Suboption 3": {"Subsub 3":203, "Subsub 4":204, "Subsub 5":205}
            }
```

[image]

How do i return `JSON` in this format from a hierarchical database?? I mean  how do i approach?? Kindly show me a direction.

**NOTE:**

[Click Here to Checkout the (jQuery) Plugin I am using](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/)

Comment: With which part of your code are you having difficulty? What have you tried?

Comment: I have learned JSON recently...and used successfully in my project..but i am kinda confused how to start. How to get the data recursively.

Comment: How are you currently accessing your database? Are you using an ORM or plain ADO.NET? How does your SQL database tables look like?

Comment: Plain ADO.NET with Enterprise Library...I have 3 columns in my table `NodeID`--->`ParentID`--->`NodeName`

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Any idea?? Just gimme a direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you are in ASP.Net you can just iterate though it using the build in functions:

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = 
         new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
string sJSON = oSerializer.Serialize(oList);
```

You can perform iterations using loops as well:

```
var productsJObject = JObject.Parse(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

foreach (var category in categories)
{
    foreach (var category2 in category.Value)
    {
        foreach (var category3 in category2.Value)
        {
            var olist = new MyList { Id = version.SelectToken("id").ToString()
                      };
        }
    }
}
```

This can be ugly but usable if you have a defined set of levels, if you are performing an Nth dimensional transition it gets very complex very fast.

You can look here for an idea:

[Java - Create JSON Object from Multiple Multidimensional Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382351/java-create-json-object-from-multiple-multidimensional-arrays)

Comment: Can you please check this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555365/json-looses-formating ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12555365/json-looses-formating) i have tried to write a code snippet but am facing some problem...kindly check.